# How can i pass list of objects as a parameter on WebApi Odata?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have problem in passing list of object as a parameter on WebApi Odata.
I have two classes:

```
public class Test{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Desc {get; set;}
  public Tests[] Tests{ get; set; }
}

 public class Tests{
     public int Entry1 {get; set;}
     public int Entry2 {get; set;}
 }
```

On the client side im passing the parameters as object:

```
var postData = {
     onTest: {
          id: data.Id, 
          desc: data.Desc 
          tests: data.Tests // here there is list of two objects
                 }
            };
```

and on WebApiConfig:

```
builder.EntitySet<Test>("Tests");
 var onTest = builder.EntityType<Test>().Collection.Action("UpdateTest");
 onTest .EntityParameter<Test>("onTest");
```

When im sendding only the Id and the Desc, they are passed ok to the controller action, but when i include the list of Test the parameters received are null.

Any suggestion how can i pass list of objects Tests to the controller through parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
onTest.CollectionEntityParameter<Test>("onTests");
```

FYI relative documentation: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support